# How to in iOS app open page in browser with additional Javascript code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I open page in safari like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://translate.yandex.com/"]];
```

I additionally want to perform some javascript code to run after page loaded. I think this is impossible, but you never know.

I know that I can show page in app UIWebView, and do what I want.

Comment: As far as I know you have to do it in a `UIWebView`. I don't know of anyway to pass javascript into the `openURL`

Comment: this is just not possible...